# Updated version of my first neural network in c++

Tags: c++, performance, machine-learning, neural-network

I got lot of suggestions for optimizing my neural network last post I made, now I wanted to post updated version of it were I got rid of most of performance eaters, now I would really appriciate **neural network side help**, because last post I only got c++ side stuff, program is working as excpected, but **relu network dies way to quickly** in network with 2 inputs, so maybe my math is incorrect somewhere in updateWeights(). (or calculateErrors())

Neural Network Class:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>

namespace ActivationFunctions
{
    struct relu
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return input * (input >= 0); }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return input >= 0; }
        } derivative;
    };

    struct lrelu
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return (input < 0) * (-derivative.a * input) + (input >= 0) * input; }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float a = 0.01f;
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return (input >= 0 ? 1 : a); }
        } derivative;
    };

    struct sigmoid
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return 1.0f / (1.0f + std::expf(-input)); }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { float s = 1.0f / (1.0f + std::expf(-input)); return s * (1.0f - s); }
        } derivative;
    };

    struct tanh
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return std::tanhf(input); }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { float t = std::tanhf(input); return 1.0f - t * t; }
        } derivative;
    };

    struct step
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return (input <= 0 ? -1 : 1); }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return 1; }
        } derivative;
    };

    struct none
    {
        float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return input; }
        struct deriv_t
        {
            float operator()(float input) const noexcept { return 1; }
        } derivative;
    };
};

template<typename Activation = ActivationFunctions::relu>
class NeuralNetwork
{
    using layer = std::vector<float>;
    using neuron_layers = std::vector<layer>;
    using batch = neuron_layers;
    using neuron_weights = std::vector<neuron_layers>;
    using size_type = size_t;
public:
    float learningRate = 0.1f;
    float weightRandRange = 0.1f;
public:
    NeuralNetwork(const std::vector<size_type>& topology)
    {
        //Resize layers to how many layers network will have
        size_type layers = topology.size() - 1;
        m_neuron_layers.resize(layers);
        m_unactivated_neuron_layers.resize(layers);
        m_neuron_layer_errors.resize(layers);

        for (size_type i = 0; i < layers; ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_layers[i].resize(topology[i + 1]);
            m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i].resize(topology[i + 1]);
            m_neuron_layer_errors[i].resize(topology[i + 1]);
        }

        srand(time(NULL));

        //Initialize weights and resize them according to last layer 
        m_neuron_weights.resize(layers);

        for (size_type i = 0; i < layers; ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_weights[i].resize(topology[i + 1]);
            for (size_type j = 0; j < topology[i + 1]; ++j)
            {
                size_type lastLayerOutputSize = topology[i];
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].resize(lastLayerOutputSize + 1);
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].back() = 0;
                for (size_type k = 0; k < lastLayerOutputSize; ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_weights[i][j][k] = initWeightRandom();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void forward(const float* inputs)
    {
        std::copy(inputs, inputs + m_inputs.size(), m_inputs.data());
        //Forwarding input layer according to network inputs
        //Multiplying weights over inputs for each input neuron using inner_product and adding bias (specified as last parameter of inner_product)
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers[0].size(); ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_layers[0][i] = m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][i] = std::inner_product(inputs, inputs + m_inputs.size(), m_neuron_weights[0][i].data(), m_neuron_weights[0][i].back());
        }

        //Forwarding other layer according to last layer's outputs in the same way
        for (size_type i = 1; i < m_neuron_layers.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_layers[i][j] = m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j] = std::inner_product(m_neuron_layers[i - 1].begin(), m_neuron_layers[i - 1].end(), m_neuron_weights[i][j].begin(), m_neuron_weights[i][j].back());
            }
        }

        //Applying activation function to neurons
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers.size() - 1; ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_layers[i][j] = m_activation(m_neuron_layers[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    void backpropagate(const float* targets)
    {
        calculateErrors(targets);
        updateWeights();
    }
    void calculateErrors(const float* targets)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers.back().size(); ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i] = targets[i] - m_neuron_layers.back()[i];
        }

        //Than using calculated output errors calculate hidden errors
        //We iterate over all the layers(except output layer) and then iterate over all the neurons in current layer
        //And then we wanna do: errors[i] = errors[i + 1] * weights[i].transpose() ("i" is layer index)
        //errors[i] and errors[i + 1] is a vector and weights[i] is a matrix
        //aligned as [inputs][neurons] (I think) so if we transpose that it will be [neurons][weights]
        //so we can translate errors[i] = errors[i + 1] * weights[i + 1].transpose(); (WARN: weights[i + 1] might be incorrect it might be weights[i])
        //to errors[i][j] += errors[i + 1][k] * weights[i + 1][k][j] ("j" is neuron index in current layer)("k" is neuron index in next layer)
        for (long i = m_neuron_layers.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] = 0;
                for (size_type k = 0; k < m_neuron_layers[i + 1].size(); ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] += m_neuron_layer_errors[i + 1][k] * m_neuron_weights[i + 1][k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void updateWeights()
    {
        //Input Weights
        for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[0].size(); ++j)
        {
            for (size_type k = 0; k < m_inputs.size(); ++k)
            {
                m_neuron_weights[0][j][k] += learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[0][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][j]) * m_inputs[k];
            }
        }
        //Weights
        for (size_type i = 1; i < m_neuron_layers.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                for (size_type k = 0; k < m_neuron_layers[i - 1].size(); ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_weights[i][j][k] += learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]) * m_neuron_layers[i - 1][k];
                }
            }
        }

        //Bias
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].back() += learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void train(const batch inputs, const batch targets)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i)
        {
            forward(inputs[i].data());
            backpropagate(targets[i].data());
        }
    }

    void train(const batch inputs, const batch targets, batch& predictions)
    {
        predictions.clear();
        predictions.resize(inputs.size());
        for (size_type i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i)
        {
            forward(inputs[i].data());
            backpropagate(targets[i].data());
            predictions[i] = m_neuron_layers.back();
        }
    }

public: //<UTILITIES>//
    const float* getOutput() const { return m_neuron_layers.back().data(); }
    void reset()
    {
        m_neuron_layers.clear();
        m_neuron_layer_errors.clear();
        m_unactivated_neuron_layers.clear();
        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_weights.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_weights.size(); ++j)
            {
                for (size_type k = 0; k < m_neuron_weights.size(); ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_weights[i][j][k] = initWeightRandom();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    float mse() const
    {
        float error = 0;
        for (const auto& x : m_neuron_layer_errors.back())
            error += x * x;
        return std::sqrt(error / m_neuron_layers.back().size());
    }
private:
    float initWeightRandom() const { return (float(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2 - 1) * float(weightRandRange); }
public: //<DEBUG>//
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const NeuralNetwork& net)
    {
        os << "Error: " << net.mse();
        return os;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::ostream_iterator<float> carr(std::cout, " | ");
        std::cout << "Network = \n{\n";

        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << ("    Layer[" + std::to_string(i) + "] = \n    {\n");
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                std::cout << ("        Neuron[" + std::to_string(j) + "] = \n        {\n");
                std::cout << ("            Weights = [ | ");
                std::copy(m_neuron_weights[i][j].begin(), m_neuron_weights[i][j].end() - 1, carr);
                std::cout << "];\n";
                std::cout << ("            Bias = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_weights[i][j].back())) + ";\n";
                std::cout << ("            Unactivated_Output = " + std::to_string(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j])) + ";\n";
                std::cout << ("            Output = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_layers[i][j]) + ";\n");
                std::cout << ("            Error = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j])) + ";\n";
                std::cout << "        };\n";
            }
            std::cout << "    }\n";
        }

        std::cout << "\n    Outputs = [ | ";
        std::copy(m_neuron_layers.back().data(), m_neuron_layers.back().data() + m_neuron_layers.back().size(), carr);
        std::cout << "];\n";

        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    layer m_inputs;
    neuron_layers m_neuron_layers;
    neuron_layers m_unactivated_neuron_layers;
    neuron_layers m_neuron_layer_errors;
    neuron_weights m_neuron_weights;
    const Activation m_activation = {};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Write only one statement per line

For some reason you decided to make all the activation functions and their derivatives one-liners. This results in some very long lines, requiring sideways scrolling. I recommend you just use one statement per line.

## Make constants `static constexpr`

The constants `a` (in `lrelu::deriv_t`), as well as `learningRate` and `weightRandRange` are never changed in the code you showed here. If they are really constant, prefer to make them `static constexpr`.

## Use `size_type` consistently

You are still using `long` in one place as an index into `m_neuron_layers`. This should be `size_type` as well. This can be done by changing the loop from:

```
for (long i = m_neuron_layers.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
```

Which unfortunately depends on `i` going negative, to:

```
for (size_type i = m_neuron_layers.size() - 1; i-- > 0;)
```

However, I would remove `size_type` completely and just use `std::size_t` everywhere. The reason is that `size_type` is only used internally, and it should never be anything but `std::size_t`.

## Naming things

Use a consistent naming scheme. Your main class name uses [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case), but the types you define with `using` inside that class are all in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Futhermore, there's `size_type` which has the suffix `_type`, but the other types don't. I recommend that you keep things as consistent as possible; either use PascalCase for all types you define, or use the `_type` suffix for all type aliases you define.

## Input/output types

Some functions, like `forward()`, take raw pointers to `float` as input, others, like `train()`, take `std::vectors` as input, by value even! The first is rather unsafe, as it doesn't pass the size of the buffer of `float`s, the latter is very inefficient, since it is making unnecessary copies.

Prefer passing inputs as `const` *references* to STL container types. (If you want to be really fancy and you can use C++20, you could make those functions take [`std::ranges::input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range)s.) Add `assert()` statements to verify that the passed input has the expected size, to catch programming errors.

For `getOutput()`, you can return a `const` reference to `m_neuron_layers.back()`.

## Avoid unnecessary copies

Apart from the unnecessary copies mentioned in the above section, you more explicitly make a copy of the input given to `forward()`. The input values are reused by `updateWeights()`, but why couldn't you just pass the same pointer/reference to `inputs` to `updateWeights()`? That would allow you to remove the member variable `m_inputs`, and avoid having to make a copy.

## Potential to use more STL algorithms

You are already using STL algorithms in `std::forward()`, but there are many places where you could use them. On the other hand, plain `for`-loops can sometimes be more readable, so I would not hold this against you.

## Use C++'s random number generators

Don't use `srand()` and `rand()`, those are C functions, and they are not particularly good for random number generation. Prefer using [C++11's random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) functionality. In particular, you should be able to replace `initWeightRandom()` with a member variable of type [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

## Unnecessary call to `clear()`

In `train()`, you are going to overwrite all the elements of `predictions` anyway, so the call to `clear()` is superfluous, and will unnecessarily cause the array to be filled with zeroes due to the call to `resize()` right afterwards. Remove the call to `clear()` and just keep the `resize()`.

## Printing results

It's weird to see `operator<<` just print the root mean square error, but having a function `print()` that prints the whole state of the neural network. I would expect them to do the same thing. If the user of this class just wants to print the error value, then they can just do that themselves, the difference in typing between `std::cout << net` and `std::cout << net.mse()` is minimal.

Comment: thanks, some mentions:
 I name all the things weirdly like that (it's just my style). 
long/int was necessary in that for loop. rand() works well mostly so why not, but still fixed it, learning rate is not static constexpr, user should be able to change that (so I prefer it to be just public member), others were fixed.

Comment: Well, if there is consistency in your weirdness it's fine I guess :) The `long` is avoidable, I've updated the answer to show how.

Answer (score 1):

All your output statements are of the form:
`std::cout << ("    Layer[" + std::to_string(i) + "] = \n    {\n");`
that is very weird.  Why are you using `to_string` and concatenating the strings for the output, rather than just using `<<` normally?

That is:  `cout << "    Layer[" << i << "] = \n    {\n";`

Comment: you are right, fixed it.